# How would i create a bash script to convert .wav files from folder [A] to mp3 format . then move them to new folder [mp3folder]

Tags: bash, audio, ffmpeg, sh, sleep

I want this Script to run in a loop every hour. The main goal is to convert the wav files that I export to my VM share folder when using Ableton.

#### Messy Idea of what I want but need lots of help with

```
for file in /mnt/hgfs/VMshare/transfer/*

do

if ["$file" == "/mnt/hgfs/VMshare/transfer/*.wav]

then 


find -name "*.wav" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k {}.mp3 \;

else 
echo "NO WAV TO CONVERT"
mv /mnt/hgfs/VMshare/transfer/*.mp3 /root/Desktop/MP3Music/
```

Comment: Can you use Python instead of BASH to handle the control flow?

Comment: Have you tried [mp3fs](https://khenriks.github.io/mp3fs/)?

Comment: mp3fs looks neat. but it seems to me its only for programs needing to view it as a mp3. does it convert them to a full usable mp3? also my python skills are weak im still training

Answer (score 0):

Change the **FILE_PATH** variable, **destination path** and **ffmpeg** command as per your need. This worked for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_PATH=/path/to/wav/format/files/*.wav
for FILE in `ls $FILE_PATH`
do
    BASENAME=`basename $FILE`
    ffmpeg -i $FILE -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192k -f mp3 `dirname "${FILE}"`/${BASENAME%.wav}.mp3 > /dev/null 2>&1
    mv `dirname "${FILE}"`/${BASENAME%.wav}.mp3 /path/to/destination/
done
```

OR

Single command:

```
find /path/to/wav/files/ -name "*.wav" -type f | xargs -I {} ffmpeg -i {} -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192k -f mp3 {}.mp3
```

But the above stores the output files as *.wav.mp3, you may need to rename it while moving to destination path.

Comment: Please, [don't parse the output of `ls`!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) here you only need `for file in $file_path; do`, `ls` is useless _and wrong!_ there are other problems and antipatterns in your code, but at least fix this one (and don't use upper case variable names).

Comment: ok yes that works for me as well . TY . so for us beginners how would i take this script and tell it to run every half hour so that the files moved into that folder will convert with time . make it a service type script ? Thanks again

Comment: @HaydenBeasley crontab is your friend. Add this **_"0,30 * * * * your_script"_** to your crontab. Make sure not to use "ls" as it may result in undefined behavior as mentioned by gniourf_gniourf

Comment: wow i should of used crontab that is super useful , thanks guys . i had some syntax errors in my script first but using the one liner and crontab it gets the job done . i'd like to see what advanced users script looks like to preform this task like a daemon of some sort , i feel that a lot of people could use this type of script for abelton or other DAW programs. The wav format does not play in most cars that i have tested . So it is important to convert it . also compression made it a lot faster to download from my website . Thanks for everybody's help

Comment: @HaydenBeasley You are welcome. Voting our post may help us future enthusiasm ;-)